# Prevent nested replacements

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am struggeling with a regex where I need to find matches from a sorted dictionary (sorted by length - long to short - to be able to match phrases) which I iterate. My solution works quite well but unfortunately only up to a specific point.

**Example**

Source: `"I do not want to make a big thing of this, because big things are bad."`

I iterate through the dictionary and let's say there is an entry `make a big thing of` with some synonyms like `overplay, stress, overstress`.

The match and replace result looks like that:

`I do not want to {make a big thing of|overplay|stress|overstress} this, because big things are bad.`

The problem starts when I come to the shorter words in my dictionary, let's say `big` with synonyms like `large, huge, massive`.

The match and replace result looks like that and starts to mess up previous replacements:

`I do not want to {make a {big|large|huge|massive} thing of|overplay|stress|overstress} this, because {big|large|huge|massive} things are bad.`

For the second `big` this might be fine, but for nested replacements there is a huge change to mess up the whole text if the iteration through the dictionary continues.

**What I need**

To not mess up the text, I need to prevent nested replacements.

So I created a rule that no "{" or "|" should appear before the word and no "|" or "}" after the word or phrase from the dictionary to check if the word or phrase is already part of a `{word|phrase|word}` structure. But that does not match words within already replaced phrases which should not be replaced (again).

**My code so far**

```
        string resultString = inText;
        string synonyms = "";
        string meaning = "";

        foreach (var item in Dictionary.WordList)
        {
            meaning = item.Key.Replace("|", "");

            try
            {
                if (meaning.Length > 1)
                {

                    var regex = new Regex(@"(?![{|])\b" + meaning + @"\b(?![\w|}])");
                    var matches = regex.Matches(resultString);

                    if (matches.Count == 0)
                        continue;

                    // in case the replacement is of a different length we replace from
                    // from back to front to keep the match indices correct
                    foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>().Reverse())
                    {
                        // use case specific reformatting
                        synonyms = item.Value.Substring(1, item.Value.Length - 2);
                        synonyms = synonyms.Replace("||", "|");

                        resultString = resultString.Replace(match.Index, match.Length, "{" + meaning + "|" + synonyms + "}");
                    }


                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: A lookahead should suffice: `currentneedle(?![^{}]*})` *(the negated character class that excludes curly brackets and the closing curly bracket ensure you are not between curly brackets.)*. You don't need to look backward if brackets are balanced.

Comment: Close, thank you!

For now, one problem is left:

`This is great and {this is|that is} cool`

if I have e. g. "his is" matches the `T(his is)` at the beginning.

I need to make sure to exactly match the word or phrase I am looking for.

Comment: No problem, if you want to be sure to find a whole word, use word-boundaries `\b` (basically its a limit between word characters that are `a-zA-Z0-9_` and an other kind of character or the limit of the string). So: `\bcurrentneedle\b(?![^{}]*})`

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much :-)